# How to find the minimum number of tiles needed to cover holes in a roof

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm just learning about dynamic programming, and I've stumbled upon a problem which I am not sure how to formulate in Python:

> Given a binary array `H` of length 55, a `1` indicates a hole in the roof, `0` indicates no hole.
>   The tails you can use have length 1, 13 or 55, and the cost to deploy each is 3, 13 and 50, respectively.
>   For a given array of holes `H` return the minimum cost such that all the holes are covered.

From what I learned, the first step is to find the base cases, and to reason by induction.
So, here are some base cases I could easily find:

- a tile of size 13 is more convenient than 5 tiles of size 1 (cost: 13 vs 15 or more)
- a tile of size 55 is more convenient than 4 tiles of size 13 (cost: 50 vs 52 or more)

Initially I thought the first point means that if there are 5 or more holes in 13 contiguous spaces I should always choose the 13 tile. However I think it depends on following holes.

The second point is even more problematic if you throw in 1-tiles in the problem. Consider, e.g., 4 single holes at locations `[0, 15, 29, 44]` you're better off with 4 1-tiles (1 x 55-tile costs 50, 4 x 13-tiles = 52).

So it looks I have to evaluate "how spaced" are the holes for all the possible combination of slices in the array are.

How can I formulate the above into (even pseudo-) code?

Comment: have you started something in python?

Comment: this sounds even more complex than the [Knapsack_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is NP-complete...

Comment: Isn't this more related to stack's [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)? #just_asking

Comment: Are you allowed to overlap tiles?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Not really, apart from trying to manipulate the input with no real direction.

Comment: @Taxellool Yeah, I was wondering... Happy for the question to be moved if most agree.

Comment: @stark the problem doesn't specify but I assume not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say cost[i] - best cost to cover first i elements of the roof.
Obviously cost[0] = 0 (we don't need any money to cover 0 tiles).

Lets describe our state as (position, cost).

From state (i,cost[i]) we can get to 4 different potential states:

- (i + 1, cost[i] + 3) (when we use tile of length 1 and cost is 3)
- (i + 13, cost[i] + 13) (tile length = 13, cost is also 13)
- (i + 55, cost[i] + 50) (tile length = 55, cost is 50)
- (i + 1, cost[i]) (we ignore current position and don't use any tile here)

Once we change state using one of the above rules we should consider:

- position should be <= total Length (55)
- if we get to position **i** with same or bigger cost we don't want to proceed (basically dynamic programming plays role here, if we get to the sub-problem with same or worse result we don't want to proceed).
- we can't skip tile (our 4th state transformation) if this tile has hole.

Once we run all this state transformations answer will be at cost[total length (55)]

Comment: I've mulled over a bit on your answer and I'm not sure I'm grasping it fully. It looks to me it could find a potentially sub-optimal solution: when you write "we can't skip tile (our 4th state transformation) if this tile has hole", doesn't it mean that the algorithm will always choose the 1-long tile rather than the 13-long tile, as cost will always be smaller (3 vs 13)? Am I missing something?

Comment: Jir, here is code example which might make things a bit easier for you https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmSHWf I'm not familiar with Python and hopefully C# will work fine for you. You can play with it directly in your browser.

Comment: Very clear now, thank you! Now I see what you meant.